# why i can't define out side of a function followed by =?

Tags: javascript, string, function, xmlhttprequest, global-variables

the code i am trying to run

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script> 
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = 'frashnum=&action=login&Frm_Logintoken="+results+"&Username=admin&Password=test';
var url = 'http://page/';
http.open('POST', url, true);
//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');


 http.onload = function () {

let str = (http.responseText);
    alert(str)
    let pattern =/\bgetObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\)\.value = "([^"]+)";/;
    let results = console.log(str.match(pattern)[1]);
    return results;

 } 
 console.log(results);
http.send(params);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i am trying to return the results variable to use it in Frm_Logintoken from the params but it says results is not defined . where clearly it's defined... so i tried to remove the equals sign before the

function and this part too http.onload = and it worked but the rest of code didn't ... so is there a way to fix this ?

i have already tried a lot of the answers from other questions but non worked for me  ... 
and i am too Beginner to understand not well Simplified answers.

so please don't mention links or mark it as 
duplicated and just answer it

Comment: That's a bit confusing. It looks like you want to use the API to retrieve the `results`, but in order to use the API, you need to have the `results` already (for the `params`)? Seems you're in a catch-22

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @04FS what i don't understand is that is there no example that's the function followed by =

Comment: just an example  is all i need .

Comment: https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-use-the-callback-function-ajax.cfm explains how to use callback functions when you are dealing with XMLHttpRequest yourself. (As opposed to a framework like jQuery encapsulating that in an a bit less cumbersome interface, or using “modern” alternatives such as the Fetch API.)

Comment: @04FS 
here is the new working code everyone
i fixed it by var response
and then response = results;
and doing two requests one get and the other is post and adding the second one in set timeout function
https://pastebin.com/mVnNDcAg
what do you think that’s wrong in this code and can be improved ?
…
here what i think i need to do.
make it redo the first request if the response is null or undefined and don’t do the second request till the response isn’t null or undefined.
but i have no clue how to do this so any help is appreciated

Comment: @CertainPerformance ............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an quick fix would be changing

```
http.open('POST', url, true);
```

to
    http.open('POST', url, false);

to make the request synchronous .
and instead of `return results;`

add results1 = results;

and then

```
console.log(results1);
```

should work .. and if not add just add

```
var results1;
```

at the start of the code

so the full code should look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script> 
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'http://page/';
var results1;
http.open('POST', url, false);
//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');


 http.onload = function () {

let str = (http.responseText);
    alert(str)
    let pattern =/\bgetObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\)\.value = "([^"]+)";/;
    let results = console.log(str.match(pattern)[1]);
    results1 = results;

 } 
 console.log(results1);
var params='frashnum=&action=login&Frm_Logintoken='+results1+'&Username=admin&Password=test';
http.send(params);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the results in the params should be in Apostrophe not double quotes so it should look like this 'results1'

Answer (score 0):

Learn the asynchronous behaviour of javascript. Your console.log(results) part is being called before the response of api call is received. Check [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: so can you fix the code in an answer ?.
and a well Simplified examples will be better than these answers " How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?"  is there a link outside of stack ?